# DataTables not found

Tags: laravel

I am using **KoolReport** Laravel page to generate report.

**Koolreport** has **DataTables** class but when i use it i got the error :

> Class 'DataTables' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\invoice\resources\views\reports\report.blade.php)

**My code :**

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>My Report</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>It works</h1>
    <?php
    DataTables::create([
        "dataSource"=>$this->dataStore("users"),
        "options"=>array(
            "paging"=>true
        )
    ]);
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include Datatable declaration as below in your Controller file.

```
<?php
use \koolreport\datagrid\DataTables;
?>
```

Or as an alternative, you can directly specify full path in blade file.

```
 \koolreport\datagrid\DataTables::create([
        "dataSource"=>$this->dataStore("users"),
        "options"=>array(
            "paging"=>true
        )
    ]);
```

Reference links :

[KoolReport datatables](https://www.koolreport.com/docs/datagrid/datatables/)

[KoolReport Blade](https://www.koolreport.com/docs/blade/overview/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `'\'`

```
@php
\DataTables::create([
    "dataSource"=>$this->dataStore("users"),
    "options"=>array(
        "paging"=>true
    )
]);
@endphp
```